# In Mobile Teams - "Cannot display PDF (icp.pdf) is of invalid format) message is getting displayed when clicking on a button

Tags: android, botframework, microsoft-teams

In Mobile Teams chatbot - "Cannot display PDF (icp.pdf) is of invalid format) message is getting displayed when clicking on a button. [image: Error Image]

Tried to open button with pdf link in Mobile Teams chatbot and expecting to view the pdf instead getting an error message. could you suggest an option to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What OS is this? Does it work on web or desktop?